# Derivative of a trace of a partitioned matrix with respect to a sub matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, matrix-calculus

I am trying to find the critical points of an optimization problem by taking the derivatives of a complicated function. One of the terms in the objective function involves taking the derivative of a partitioned matrix with respect to a sub-matrix of it. So the problem can be casts as given below:

Suppose $X$ is partitioned as \begin{bmatrix} x_1 & X_2^\top \end{bmatrix}

where $x_1$ is a $m \times 1$ vector. How to find the derivative of
$$
\text{tr}(A X)
$$
with respect to $X_2$?

Comment: Since $dx_1 = 0 dX_2$ it should be $[0 \quad A^T]$

Answer (score 2):

$
\def\TR{\operatorname{trace}}
\def\m#1{\left[\begin{array}{c|c}#1\end{array}\right]}
\TR(AX)$ should not be thought of as a function, but rather as a Frobnius product $(:)$ or as an elementwise sum
$$f \;=\; \TR(AX) \;=\; (A^T:X) \;\doteq\;\sum_j\sum_k A_{jk}^T\,X_{jk}$$
You can partition $X$ **any** way you wish, as long as you partition $A^T$ the **same** way, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
X &= \m{
x_1 & x_3 & \ldots \\\hline
x_2 & x_4 & \ldots \\
}
\qquad
A^T = \m{
a_1^T & a_3^T & \ldots \\\hline
a_2^T & a_4^T & \ldots \\
} \\\\
f &= \sum_i\:(a_i^T:x_i) \;=\; \sum_i\:\TR(a_ix_i) \\
}$$
The gradient wrt any single partition is obviously the corresponding partition of $A^T$
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}=a_i^T \qquad\qquad
\frac{\partial f}{\partial X_{jk}}=A_{jk}^T 
$$

Comment: What is referred to as $A_{jk}^\top$?

Comment: @shani You can think of them either as the scalar components of the **transpose** of $A,\:$ or as a partitioning of $A^T$ into $\tt1x1$ matrices.